What could have been done better in United Airlines Flight 232 when differential thrust was used?
In United Airlines Flight 232, on their DC-10, all hydraulic fluid and pressure was lost on all three systems, simultaneously. Fitch, who was a training check airman on the DC-10 was on board and happened to have experimented and practiced using differential thrust on his own time (in the simulator) to see if he could fly the DC-10 just with differential thrust alone.
While I think no one in the world could have done a better job than Fitch in this case (and it seems the rest of the crew misunderstood up to the very last second how differential thrust worked by reading their transcribed comments — telling Fitch to do things that didn't make sense), I'm still curious, what (if anything) could have been done better? Were any reports produced that commented on (I hope also praised) Fitch's effort, and suggested improvements?
In particular, I'm curious what Fitch's plan was. If he hadn't been unlucky at the very last second, when the wing tipped, touching the ground, and the engine was too slow to respond to correct this, what would have happened next? The plane is now on the tarmac and heading down the runway at 220 knots or so. Is there even any stopping power available? I'm sure the brakes also run on hydraulic power, or is this a separate system?
If there is no way to slow down, is it obvious that it is better to let the plane hurdle off the end of the runway, instead of a controlled crash?
I know that differential thrust was attempted in the simulator in the wake of the crash to see if they could establish some differential thrust emergency procedure, but that the pilots who attempted this couldn't even match Fitch's performance.
In any case, is there even anything theoretical to say about this, or is it to this day (this was in 1989) still considered a hopeless situation and death sentence? How do you stop if you even get on the runway?
I'll accept some educated reasoning as a valid answer, and also accept (obviously) links to any official or academic reports that address this.

Brake accumulators can provide several applications of the wheel brakes even with no hydraulic system pressure.

NTSB report for N1819U accident, on July 19, 1989, summarized here. This experience helped in a somehow similar hydraulic failure of a A300 after a missile strike over Baghdad in 2003
